# Build a Maze Game Tutorial; Label control being used as Wall

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dd492162%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) tutorial, they chose to use a Label control to act as the "Walls" for the Maze game. Now I can understand how a Label can be used in this manner, but I would've thought it would've made more sense to use a Panel control as a Wall. Their choice seems a bit odd to me.

Is there a good explanation as to why one would use a Label control instead of a Panel control?

I did notice that the tutorial states:

> This may seem somewhat unusual because a Label control is meant to be
>   used as a label. In this case, the label is used as a drawing block
>   because it works. An important part of programming is recognizing when
>   a tool in your toolbox (or, in this case, your IDE's Toolbox) works
>   for the job, even if it's not the job it was originally intended for.

But I still don't understand why a Label control is a better fit for this "job" than a Panel control.

Comment: Why is this question "too broad"?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author. AFAIK, nobody here can read minds. But given that making a maze game using winforms control is kind of silly to start with, the choice of which control to use seems a little irrelevant.

Comment: The answer: there is no good reason. Both controls have the [Control.MouseEnter Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'd also say that box out comment in the tutorial makes me cringe. Using some tool "because you have it" rather than finding the *right* tool sounds like the start of many ugly hacks.

Comment: I guess there is no big difference and reason in using a label or a panel here or even a button at least. Maybe performance reasons? Maybe the author wanted to hold the tutorial as easy as possible for beginners (A `label` tells somebody more than a `panel`)

Comment: @MattBurland This is not true. I have seen posts from Jon Skeet that answer questions as they where thought, not written... he is just amazing

Comment: What confused me though was the fact that the author considers using a Label control "a better tool" for the job than, say, a Panel control. I just can't figure out why anybody would think that using a Label would be a better way to make a wall. The only reason I can come up with is for performance reasons but still - I have no idea how to prove that.

Comment: [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/) would be a better tool for the job. This is a tutorial showing something contrived and giving a contrived answer, you shouldn't get too hung up on this.

Comment: @MattBurland It is about the *"AFAIK, nobody here can read minds."* part of your first comment. I am not sure whether Jon can actually read minds.

Comment: @Matt I believe he's referring to your comment about people not being able to read minds.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Ah! fair enough. In that case I absolutely agree. Although we are talking about the mind of the original tutorial author rather than the OP. Not sure if Jon's powers extend that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the tutorial already states:

> ...the label is used as a drawing block because it works...

In most cases, the reason *"because it works"* is short for:

*"There is no deeper rationale about that, it seems to do what was expected, so better do not touch that and do not question it because I do not know better myself."*

So: Anything fitting is a possible drop-in replacement for `label`.

Keep asking yourself, this is the right way to get a good developer!

but: Hey, this is just a simple example